# Why does unimplemented abstract type compile in scala?

Tags: scala, abstract-type

Consider the following simple example:

```
trait Foo {
  type Bar
}

class Baz extends Foo // <-- no compile error
```

I don't understand how the last statement compiles when clearly `type Bar` wasn't implemented by concrete type `class Baz` (FWIW, marking it `final` also produced the same result).

And it only fails to compile when I actually try access the `type Bar` through path-dependent type.

```
val baz: new Baz
val bazBar: baz.Bar = new baz.Bar // <-- compile error
```

What's even more interesting is that at type-level, signature actually does compile but it only fails when I access at value-level through `new baz.Bar`.

In other words, the following **does** compile:

```
val bazBar: baz.Bar = ???
```

This is quite unintuitive as it deviates from the way of other abstract members.

Why does unimplemented abstract type not raise compile error? Am I missing something?